# location of pip-build-root with homebrew

Tags: django, pip

I installed the python framework using homebrew and when I install django, I am forced to install version 1.5.1, but I want to work with 1.4.3.  When I try to uninstall and reinstall it gives me this

```
 Requested Django==1.4.3, but installing version 1.5.1
```

I have run into this problem before and the solution was to clear the pip-build-root dir located in /tmp.  However, now that I have installed pip through homebrew, I cant find the pip-build-root.  I have looked in /tmp and /.pip, nothing, any ideas?

Comment: One thing I have thought of doing is (if possible) start over and not use homebrew.  Anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Can you tell us what commands you issued to uninstall/reinstall Django?

Comment: pip install Django==1.4.3

Comment: Take a look at my answer about doing this with virtualenv rather than homebrew.  Also, trying `pip uninstall Django` before reinstalling it.

Comment: This does not work, it will still detect the previous pip build of the newer version

Answer (score 0):

**In light of your comment about doing this outside of Homebrew...**
It's probably a better idea to install Django into a virtual environment rather than install it via Homebrew (which makes it available system-wide).

There are a number of good places to learn about how to do this.  I've found Jeff Knupp's (@jknupp) article about Starting a Django 1.4 Project the Right Way (http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/10/24/starting-a-django-14-project-the-right-way/) a good place to start.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.  My main problem ended up being that pip was installed when I ran `brew install python --framework`, so everytime I ran `pip install` it was going through homebrew.  I fixed this by running `brew uninstall python` and starting over.